# How can I auto run script in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, autorun

I have Google Form populated spreadsheet that I added function using script code. 
Which is auto fill column S using script set formula.

But, after every Form submission, I have to manual run to activate the script.

I want it auto run and update the column `S` based on column `P`.

Initially, from `'myFunction'`, I changed to `'onEdit'`, but still unable to auto run.

```js
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("S3").setFormula('=IFS(P3="Pending Review","Red", P3="Released","Green",P3="In Progress","Yellow",P3="Closed (Unable to link back)","Black")');

  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var fillDownRange = ss.getRange(3,19,lr-2);
  ss.getRange("S3").copyTo(fillDownRange);

}
```

Comment: See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/125302/how-to-re-calculate-a-google-sheet-every-time-a-google-forms-questionnaire-is-su

Answer (score 1):

### Instead of onEdit use onFormSubmit

This is an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that you need to bind to your function by

- Going from the UI to Edit->Current Project triggers
- -> Create a new trigger
- Event type: On form submit

[image]

> This trigger will run your function on every form submit, provided
>   your spreadsheet is set as the destination spreadsheet for your form.